# JsonNetValueProviderFactory does not deserialize JSON from AngularJS post

Tags: ajax, json, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an asp.net MVC application.

In my global.asax:

```
ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Add(new JsonNetValueProviderFactory());
```

if I use jquery ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: urlPostInvitation,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: $.toJSON($scope.invitation),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data) {
        alert('Yes');
    }
});
```

Everything works fine, but if I use AngularJS ajax

```
$http({
    url: urlPostInvitation,
    method: "POST",
    data: $scope.invitation,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' }
}).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    alert("Yes");
});
```

I get an empty object in the server.

With JsonValueProviderFactory everything works fine, but not with JsonNetValueProviderFactory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer myself, the jQuery ajax post adds the header: 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'

If I add this in the AngularJs call it works

Answer (score 0):

If you output $scope.invitation and $.toJSON($scope.invitation) to the console do they look the same?